# Non repeating monthly SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in which I would like to return the number of users who have logged in for the month without repeating the record in the next month.

If a user has logged in April and May, it only shows one record for April. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.userid), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.loginTime) as month 
FROM login_audit a LEFT JOIN user u on u.userid = a.userid 
WHERE a.loginTime <= '2012-12-31 11:59:59' 
AND a.loginTime >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY month
```

So far the records are returning

```
userid    month
1        1
2        1
1        2
3        2
```

In this scenario, user 1 is coming up for both January and Februray. I would like it to ommit that record. Either that or have it accumulated. Like so:

Either

```
userid    month
1        1
2        1
3        2
```

Or

```
userid    month
1        1
2        1
1        2
2        2
3        2
```

I hope this made sense. Please ask me anything if you'd like any further clarifications. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using `GROUP BY a.userid`.

Comment: if a user has April, May, and June, you want to show only April? And if he has also October and November, do you want to show both April and October?

Comment: Hi @fthiella yes that's the idea. If a user has logged in for the year, it only needs to show up once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't see where you need table user...

For first "wanted scenario" :

```
SELECT 
  a.userid, 
  MIN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.loginTime)) as month 
FROM login_audit a
WHERE a.loginTime <= '2012-12-31 11:59:59' AND a.loginTime >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY a.userid
```

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. Thank you so much! Btw, I need the user table to sort by department. I left that out to shorten the query but I could see what you meant. Thanks again.

Comment: @sas1ni69 Too many compliments, I'm blushing ;) Thought there was something like that with table user, but... not in the given sample. You're welcome !

Comment: you deserve them! :D It really helped turn the solution to something a little more elegant than what it was :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use this approach.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.userid), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.loginTime) as month 
FROM login_audit a 
WHERE a.loginTime <= '2012-12-31 11:59:59' 
AND a.loginTime >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00' 

and not exists
(select userid
from login_audit
where login_audit.user_id = a.user_id
and carry on with date range for the following month
)
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you so much but this was the old approach which was a little slower but it definitely works. Thanks a lot.